# how to cast one type to another while preserving value category and cv-qualifiers?

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

As the title says. C++ already has `std::forward`, but it can't cast the original type to another. I wonder if there is a function to cast one type to another while preserving the value category and cv-qualifers of the original type.

Supposing there is such a function called `perfect_cast` to do the magic, the output of the following code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <format>

template <typename To, typename From>
decltype(auto) perfect_cast(From&& s)
{
    // ???
}

template <std::size_t I>
struct A
{
    void f()&
    {
        std::cout << std::format("lvalue A{:d}", I) << std::endl;
    }
    void f() const&
    {
        std::cout << std::format("const lvalue A{:d}", I) << std::endl;
    }
    void f()&&
    {
        std::cout << std::format("rvalue A{:d}", I) << std::endl;
    }
    void f() const&&
    {
        std::cout << std::format("const rvalue A{:d}", I) << std::endl;
    }
};

template <std::size_t ...Is>
struct B : A<Is>... {};

auto g1()
{
    return B<0, 1, 2, 3>{};
}

const auto g2()
{
    return B<0, 1, 2, 3>{};
}

int main()
{
    B<0, 1, 2, 3> b;
    auto& b1 = b;
    perfect_cast<A<0>>(b1).f();
    const auto& b2 = b1;
    perfect_cast<A<1>>(b2).f();
    perfect_cast<A<2>>(g1()).f();
    perfect_cast<A<3>>(g2()).f();
}
```

should be

```
lvalue A0
const lvalue A1
rvalue A2
const rvalue A3
```

Comment: To what object would your `A0` lvalue refer?

Comment: (1) Find the source of `std::forward` (2) Adapt it so that there is a "from" type and a "to" type. Note that you **will** need to use both "from" and "to" type in calls, so `perfect_cast<A,B>(b)`. There is a reason why calls to `std::forward` require a template parameter and it is still valid in your case.

Comment: Having said that, there isn't really a compelling use case for `perfect_cast`. `std_forward` is necessary in template code where you know neither the type nor the value category, and you want to preserve both. Knowing the type but not the value category doesn't look like a realistic scenario.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. What would `perfect_cast` return for `double d=1.0; perfect_cast<int>(d);`? To preserve lvalue, the return type would need to be `int&`. But to what would this reference be bound?

Comment: @DanielLangr It would fail to compile.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Still, my question is the same. If an argument of `perfect_cast` would be lvalue of type `double`, and the call expression should be lvalue of type `int`, how would this be possible to implement? You say that it is possible by adapting `std::foward`, but I don't see it. Could you provide some demo code?

Comment: @DanielLangr The answer is the same too. It will be implemented as a compilation error.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. So the answer to the OP's question is that it is not possible? That's my opinion, but your previous comment indicated something else (as I understood them).

Comment: @DanielLangr OP focuses on valid casts such as `derived&` to `base&`. This is possible. What *you* are asking for is not.

Comment: @DanielLangr A straightforward adaptation of `std::forward` would result in UB in your scenario rather than compilation error (just like a straight cast from `int&` to `double&` will). It is possible to add compile-time asserts to prevent such this from compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't a lot of use cases for a combined conversion-forward. Arguably, most casts result in prvalues, and for derived-to-base casts, the language already permits treating the derived as base, preserving value category.

For example, the OP `main` would be more clearly written as:

```
B<0, 1, 2, 3> b;
auto& b1 = b;
b1.A<0>::f();
const auto& b2 = b1;
b2.A<1>::f();
g1().A<2>::f();
g2().A<3>::f();
```

See https://godbolt.org/z/Kff9zKPha

Perhaps it is useful to know there is a seemingly related problem of forwarding an object `x` in the manner of some other object `y`. This is useful (say, if `x` is "part" of `y`). That is useful enough that it was standardized as `std::forward_like`. (It is more complex than it should have to be, because of some past poor language design decisions.)